# How to validate XML-RPC post creation and cancel when needed?

Tags: posts, actions, xml-rpc

I have an [IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/wordpress) that creates posts for me on some occasion, but for some weird reason it creates three, sometimes four posts of the same content.

I would like to add an `add_action` hook/callback to validate what will be a new post and, if it already exists, cancel the post, or move it to trash or something like it.

I found the the `xmlrpc_prepare_post` but I don't think I can cancel it from there. Unless I can update some attribute and set it to trash?

**Update.**

I tried the following and it only ever gets into the xmlrpc_call, but never ever inside xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_meta. I even added a hard-coded add_filter call (not just in case of if newPost) and my logs never show such logging message.

Here's the code:

```
function hueman_xmlrpc_call( $method )
{
    error_log("XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = $method \n" , 3, '/home/.../debug.log');
    if( 'wp.newPost' === $method || 'metaWeblog.newPost' === $method )
    {
        error_log("XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call  method = " . $method . " \n" , 3, '/home/.../debug.log');
        add_filter( 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data', 'hueman_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data' );
    }
}
add_action('xmlrpc_call', 'hueman_xmlrpc_call', 1 );


add_filter( 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data', 'hueman_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data' );

function hueman_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data( $post_data )
{
    error_log("XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data  \n" , 3, '/home/.../debug.log');
    // Check if the post title exists:
    $tmp = get_page_by_title( 
        $post_data['post_title'], 
        OBJECT, 
        $post_data['post_type'] 
    );

    if( is_object ( $tmp ) )
    {
        // Go from 'insert' to 'update' mode within wp_insert_post():
        //$post_data['ID'] = $tmp->ID; 

        $post_data['post_status'] = 'trash';
        error_log("XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data I TRASHED IT! \n" , 3, '/home/.../debug.log');
    }

    return $post_data;  
}
```

In the logs, I have this kind of log statements:

```
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = mt.supportedMethods 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = metaWeblog.getRecentPosts 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = mt.supportedMethods 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = metaWeblog.getRecentPosts 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = mt.supportedMethods 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = metaWeblog.getRecentPosts 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = metaWeblog.getCategories 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call Method = metaWeblog.newPost 
XMLRPC | hueman_xmlrpc_call  method = metaWeblog.newPost
```

Then, I see other filters I added when an article is created. I know I will probably end-up fixing the articles there but I'm sure this XMLRPC filters/actions should work.

From the logs, I see it go inside the if newPost and adding the filter 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data' but it never executes the hueman_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data function... :(

Comment: A _very_ good (and interesting) question. Might you please file an [edit] and explain how IFTTT works together with WP, how you set it up and how you point to the XML-RPLC interface? Please be as verbose as possible as this has the potential to become a very epic question. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually very simple. I used IFTTT with the RSS 2 Wordpress recipe. Plugged in my author RSS feed from the external site. In the Wordpress I logged in user my regular Wordpress user.

here's the channel: https://ifttt.com/wordpress
and the recipe: https://ifttt.com/recipes/19382-rss-feed-to-wordpress-blog

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the `xmlrpc_prepare_post` filter is only applied to the output of the `wp_getPost` and `wp_getRevision` methods of the `wp_xmlrpc_server` class.

It would be great if this code line:

```
do_action( 'xmlrpc_call', 'wp.newPost' );
```

would be replaced with extra input arguments, for example:

```
do_action( 'xmlrpc_call', 'wp.newPost', ..., $content_struct );
```

but that's not going to happen according to this [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25264).

So we need to find another way around this.

### Possible workarounds:

Here are some untested ideas using the `xmlrpc_call` and the `xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data` filters.

**Modify input data before it's inserted with `wp_insert_posts()`:**

```
/**
 * Prevent duplicate posts when doing wp.newPost via XML-RPC
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/157261/26350
 */

add_action( 'xmlrpc_call', 'wpse_xmlrpc_call' );

function wpse_xmlrpc_call( $method )
{
    if( 'wp.newPost' === $method )
        add_filter( 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data' );
}

function wpse_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data( $post_data )
{
    // Check if the post title exists:
    $tmp = get_page_by_title( 
        $post_data['post_title'], 
        OBJECT, 
        $post_data['post_type'] 
    );

    // Go from 'insert' to 'update' mode within wp_insert_post():
    if( is_object ( $tmp ) )
        $post_data['ID'] = $tmp->ID; 

    return $post_data;  
}
```

Here we try to find an existing post with the same title, during `wp.newPost` calls. If we find one, we add it's `ID` to the `$post_data` array, so it will be updated instead.

Notice that we could also have modified the `post_status` instead with:

```
    $post_data['post_status'] = 'trash';
```

so all extra inserts are directed to the *trash*.

You could also try to [create your own](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending) *insert* method via the `xmlrpc_methods` filter.

I hope you can modify this to your needs, assuming this will work ;-)

**Update**: I've now tested this idea and it works, I can both trash the duplicated posts or update it directly.

Thanks to @DavidPeterson for noticing my silly PHP syntax errors from when I edited the code within the WPSE editor ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I implemented your solution, hopefully it will work properly and place all duplicate in the trash. I'll know next time the XMLRPC gets triggered!

Comment: Hello, it did not work as intended. See below what I did. :(

Comment: Hi @vallieres, thanks for reporting back. Hopefully I can find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @birgire, it really seems to be area where documentation and/or examples are not to be found. You might think I'm not the only one that wants to filter XMLRPC articles...

Comment: were you able to make it work? On my end, it does not seem to work at all :(

Comment: Hi, I've now tested this idea and it works for my setup, both *trashing* and *updating*. I see that you used `metaWeblog.newPost` but I used `wp.newPost`. I also had a typo where I wrote `$post_type` instead of `$post_data`, sorry about that ;-)

Comment: see my updated question. Seems to never go in the right filter...

Answer (score 1):

In the wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php file

Inside the function mw_newPost() after these lines:

```
$post_title = isset( $content_struct['title'] ) ? $content_struct['title'] : null;
$post_content = isset( $content_struct['description'] ) ? $content_struct['description'] : null;
```

Add:

```
global $wpdb;
$some_post = $wpdb->get_row("
    SELECT ID
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_title = '{$post_title}'
");
```

And create a statement:

```
if (!empty($some_post->ID) and $some_post->ID > 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    // the rest of the code that already exists in the function
    /*
    $post_status = $publish ? 'publish' : 'draft';
    ...
    return strval($post_ID);
    */
}
```

Comment: Hi, ingenious solution but that would be easily overriden by any Wordpress update following the change. Any way to make it work from a plugin or functions.php ?

Comment: @Vallieres, Yes, you're right, then I've disabled WordPress updates. I wanna create a plugin soon.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous solutions were working for me (maybe because I´m posting using ***metaWeblog.newPost***)

So I made my own:

1-Make a copy of xmlrpc.php and rename to xmlrpc2.php to stay safe from WordPress updates.

2-Paste the code below this part:

```
/** Include the bootstrap for setting up WordPress environment */
require_once __DIR__ . '/wp-load.php';
```

Paste this code to prevent duplicate titles:

```
$mixml = file_get_contents('php://input');
$mixml2 = simplexml_load_string($mixml);
$json = json_encode($mixml2);

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$nextok=false;
//Sorry for the noob parsing :)
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {   
    if ($val=="title") $nextok=true;    
    if (($key=="string")&&($nextok)) { 
        $nextok=false;      
        $post_id = post_exists($val);
        //already exists, so I break the posting with exit
        if ($post_id) exit;                             
    }                   
}
```

**Explanation**:

1. Read the XMLRPC input.
2. Include post.php so we can use **post_exists** later.
3. Get the post title. Sorry for the dirty parsing :) you will
   probably want to improve it.
4. If the title already exists (even in recycle bin) we use **exit** so
   nothing is posted.

You can modify the original **xmlrpc.php** file, but you may lose the changes in future updates.

Renaming xmlrpc.php file is recommended since some servers block that file path and some brute force attacks target it.