# XMLRPC Avoid duplicate content

Tags: wp-insert-post, xml-rpc

I want to avoid duplicate post content via xmlrpc. So:

if post exists nothing happens... .
if  does not exists data insertion occurs... .

The method for  checking  would be post title or post content.
I saw [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157230/how-to-validate-xml-rpc-post-creation-and-cancel-when-needed) but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you add a reference to my previous answer, let me share how I tested it:

### Setup on site A - XML-RPC Client

```
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php' );
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php' );

$client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT( 'http://example.tld/xmlrpc.php' ); // <-- Change!
$client->debug = true;

$result = $client->query( 
    'wp.newPost', 
    [
        0,
        "username",    //<-- Change!
        "password",    //<-- Change!
        [
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_title'   => 'xml-rpc testing',
            'post_content' => 'hello xml-rpc! Random: ' . rand( 0, 999 ),
        ]
    ]
);
```

where you have to modify the *path*, *username* and *password* to your needs.

*If I recall correctly, [this great article](http://jumping-duck.com/tutorial/using-xml-rpc-in-wordpress/) by Eric Mann helped me regarding the client setup code, when I tested my plugin last year.*

### Setup on site B - XML-RPC Server

Here we add the following plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Avoid XML-RPC Post Title Duplication
 * Description: Prevent duplicate posts when doing wp.newPost via XML-RPC
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/157261/26350
 */

add_action ('xmlrpc_call', 'wpse_xmlrpc_call' );  /////

function wpse_xmlrpc_call( $method )
{
    if( 'wp.newPost' === $method )
        add_filter( 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data' );
}////

function wpse_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data( $post_data )
{
    // Check if the post title exists:
    $tmp = get_page_by_title( 
        $post_data['post_title'], 
        OBJECT, 
        $post_data['post_type'] 
    );

    // Go from 'insert' to 'update' mode within wp_insert_post():
    if( is_object ( $tmp ) )
        $post_data['ID'] = $tmp->ID; 

    return $post_data;  
}
```

### Tests

**Before activating our plugin:**

If client A creates three posts with the same title, but different content, then they will show up like this on site B:

[image: before]

Here we see that those three posts are all created on the server B as new posts.

**After activating our plugin:**

Now if client A creates a post, then it will show up on server B like this:

[image: after2]

Then client A creates another post, with the same title, but different content. Now the previous post is modified:

[image: after3]

The post list will show up like this:

[image: after1]

so we have avoided post duplication.

### Notes

Make sure site B has XML-RPC enabled.

Comment: Thank you. It works! a couple of question. 
if I wanted to no nothing on duplication (do not update..) what should I do?
If there is 200 duplicate requests per minute do I have to be concerned about it's performance?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. To avoid the duplication, I add the corresponding value to the ID field. So without that part, we would get a duplication. Regarding 200 req/min that depends on the server setup and number of posts. You should test your install for that kind of updates. I'm not sure if xml-rpc setup in WordPress supports bulk inserts, but I just want to mention that there are some ways to improve `wp_insert_post`, e.g. [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/102349/26350) but that's most likely not relevant here where there are only single inserts each time.  @DavidPeterson

Comment: but I guess by *to do nothing*, you mean to only allow modifications `x` times a minute? You might then check when the post was last modified and throw an `IXR_Error` error if it's too early. @DavidPeterson

Comment: I just realized that it doesn't work... .
I created a log file per each line and noticed that thr (add_filter( 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data' );) never goes to the plugin function ( wpse_xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data)... .
notice that there were some mistyping in your code and I edited the answer... .

Comment: Thanks for the edit and sorry for the silly syntax errors, they came from my previous answer that I copied into my answer here. I just checked the edited code, and it's running fine on my install ;-) @DavidPeterson