# Avoid duplicate posts with xml rpc

Tags: plugins, xml-rpc, duplicates

I'm new to Wordpress and I'm not a developer. I'm running an IFTT applet that posts a WordPress post each time I upload a new video on my Youtube Channel.

There is a bug with IFTT. It often posts the same post 2 or 3 times.

Therefore, I'd like to avoid duplicates before they are published. I read on forums that I needed to add a XML RPC plugin.

I tried this solution (Set up on Site B) [XMLRPC Avoid duplicate content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205399/xmlrpc-avoid-duplicate-content)

I added the code using Insert PHP Code Snippet Wordpress plugin.

But it doesn't work for me. I still have duplicate posts coming in.

---

I also created a plugin file and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem and nothing was working for me, so I posted my solution here:

[How to validate XML-RPC post creation and cancel when needed?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157230/how-to-validate-xml-rpc-post-creation-and-cancel-when-needed/370917#370917)

Maybe you want to check it.

I hope it helps!